# How do I capture words wrapped in parentheses with a regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this string named **jumpball**

```
u'\n               (12:00) Jump Ball Hibbert vs Bosh (Chalmers gains possession)\n            '
```

I want to extract **Hibbert**, **Bosh** and **Chalmers**

I can find the first by:

```
roadJumper = re.findall(r'Ball(.*?)vs',jumpball)
```

The other two names I want to find are before and after a opening parentheses **"("** and I don't know how to work around it.

I think I should be able to use **lookahead** and **lookbehind** to avoid the parentheses but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Could you improve your title? No one is going to conduct an internet search for 'a couple basic questions on Regex'. The title really is unhelpful to other people.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?  It seems to me like it would be much easier to split the string into words and use the right indices.

Comment: I could do it that way, but I am just starting to learn Regex and so I figured I would try it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> print re.search("(\w+) vs (\w+) \(\s?(\w+)",my_string).groups()
(u'Hibbert', u'Bosh', u'Chalmers')
```

Comment: Read the question carefully, this isn't what is being asked for.

Comment: there now it does what he asks for ... not very elegant though

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is how to escape parenthesis, am I right?

Try something like this:

r'Ball (\w+) vs (\w+) \((\w+)'

Notice that the third opening parenthesis is escaped.

If you are now learning how to use regexes I recommend you read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) first, if not yet